# How to recursively scan and save directory and subdirectories into database without timeout error

Tags: php, ajax, directory, subdirectory, readdir

I need to get all directories including subdirectories separately and save in db.
Right now I have a function which uses readdir and does what I want just fine. However, the problem happens when user has huge number of directories and php execution time limit which he cannot change due to shared hosting. What I want to do is to make it ajax based and divide the process into portions, so for example, each ajax request scans and saves 100 or more directories, but I cannot figure out where to stop scanning and how to resume from point I stopped in previous ajax request. I am hoping to get some hints from experts, please suggest if you have any idea on how to do it.